# Avoiding an augmented space

Tags: xetex, line-spacing

I'm struggling to do something on LaTeX and I dont know if it is possible to do :

If I write an expression like `\displaystyle \frac{a}{n}` in a sentence, that goes to a new line. The  space between the two lines is wide because of the display of the fraction. Is there a way to cancel this auto-space ?

Comment: Culd you post a  minimal, yet complete, example?

Comment: If you use `\displaystyle\frac{a}{n}` in a sentence you completely spoil the line spacing. Either use `\frac{a}{n}` or, better, `a/n`.

Comment: tex's \textsytyle math layout is explictly designed to try to preserve the line spacing, if you force it to use \displaystyle then naturally the linespacing will be uneven.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably have to drop \displaystyle, as this adds extra space in order to display in-line math as an equation-style math. If you still want a fraction in display style, it's shorter to use `$\dfrac{a}{n}$`

If you want your fraction to take less space, try using \textstyle or \scriptstyle instead.

`$\textstyle \frac{a}{n}$` is equivalent to `$\tfrac{a}{n}$` and makes fractions quite compact in text.

To make your fraction really small subscript-sized, try using `$\scriptstyle \frac{a}{n}$`

Using `$\frac{a}{n}$` will automatically decide which style to choose for displaying your fraction.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to override the normally due spacing for `\dispalystyle` math expressions. That is to use `\smash` which literally smashes the taller box containing the expression, and levels the line-spacing at par with other lines.  However a smash makes the expression blind, and may result in collision between letters.

This could eventually be avoided with a `\raisebox{..}{...}`.  The problem of using a `\raisebox` is however three-fold.  First it takes a text input, so `\text{$..$}` is needed to denote the arguments; secondly the amount by which each sub-expression has to be raised (or lowered) needs to be manually fine-tuned; lastly the code becomes nearly illegible after so many manipulations.  But if I want to achieve this fine-tuning, I think some sacrifice is necessary.

This example might be illustrative:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Suppose we want to find out how much\\
line-spacing is needed for math expressions.

With a \verb|textstyle| expression like $\tfrac{a}{n}$\\
and something in-between just to fill space,\\
and a \verb|displaystyle| expression like $\dfrac{a}{n}$\\
the line spacings are evidently unequal.\\
However, if we use a \verb|\smash| as in \smash{$\dfrac{a}{n}$}\\
we will get the normal spacing, though\\
there may be overlaps\,!

For some special cases, like $a/n$ \\ 
\verb|\raisebox| may give us the form 
      \smash{$\dfrac{\text{\raisebox{-1ex}{$a$}}}
                    {\text{\raisebox{.7ex}{$n$}}}$}\\
which may look perfect, but is by no\\
means a simple general solution\,!!
\end{document}
```

with an **output**:

[image]